# Value not properly bind in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ms-word, ckeditor, ms-office

I have used CkEditor, in which I want to upload .doc file. Now, a simple text can be set to the editor, but when a document has a \r\r\r value then it gives me an error. Below is my code for that and I have also attached a screenshot of the value.

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {


                string retString = string.Empty;
                DocumentManagementSystemEntities db = new DocumentManagementSystemEntities();
                var file = Request.Files[0];

                string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                if (fileExt == ".docx" || fileExt == "doc")
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Document/"), fileName);
                        try
                        {
                            file.SaveAs(path);

                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                            object readOnly = true;
                            object wordPath = path;
                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(
                            ref wordPath,
                            ref miss,
                            ref readOnly,
                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
                            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
                            {
                                //retString += "<br/>" + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
                                retString += docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
                            }


                            ViewBag.DocumentData = retString.ToString();

                            ViewBag.result = "Document Successfully Upload!";

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.result = "Document Not Support";
                }
```

[image]

I am binding the value in viewdata and give it to CKEditor like given:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table style="margin-top:50px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.Data, new { id= "editor1" })
    @*<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>*@
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="~/ckeditor/plugins/filebrowser/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/browser/browse.php',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/uploader/upload.php'
    });
    var myJsVariable = '@ViewBag.DocumentData'


    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(myJsVariable);

</script>
```

Comment: still in search of answer